# How can I parse a value into the appropriate target type

Tags: java, object

I have a method which has a two parameters value:Object and initialValueType:String.

```
public Object parseValueForInitialValueType(Object value, String initialValueType) {
    Class<?> clazz = Class.forName(initialValueType);
    Constructor<?> constructor = clazz.getConstructor(String.class);
    return constructor.newInstance(value);
}
```

This parameters may have following values:

```
value -> "test":String; initialValueType -> "java.lang.String"; method output -> "test":String
value -> 123.0:Double; initialValueType -> "java.lang.Double"; method output -> 123.0:Double
value -> "456.0":String; initialValueType -> "java.lang.Double"; method output -> "426.0:Double
value -> "123.000":String; initialValueType -> "java.math.BigDecimal"; method output -> 123.000:BigDecimal
```

Issue is that, I get exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: argument type mismatch
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
```

How can I parse value into desired initialValueType?

Basically, I want to construct a new object for initialValueType.

Comment: Well, your argument `123.0` obviously doesn't work, when your code always looks for a constructor using `String`. This means you need a third parameter in your method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like solution:

```
public Object parseValueForInitialValueType(Object value, String initialValueType) {
    Class<?> clazz = Class.forName(initialValueType);
    Constructor<?> constructor = clazz.getConstructor(String.class);
    return constructor.newInstance(String.valueOf(value));
}
```